# Create and shoutdown ExecutorService instance in multiuser JSP J2EE appication

Tags: java, jsp, threadpool, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

We have a multiuser token based JSP application.
We manage all sessions in a dedicated class `SessionManager`.
The later initializes a session and cached it in a map when a new user opens any application page (usually home page), and destroys this session when the associated token is not valid any more. So, we have `SessionManager::init` and `SessionManager::destroy`.

Recently I introduced `ExecutorService` in our application for some asynchronous tasks started from front end via AJAX calls and for some time consuming methods.

I create and set the `ExecutorService` instance as session attribute in `SessionManager::init`, and shut down this instance (as recommended by Oracle) in `SessionManager::destroy`. This way we have separate `ExecutorService` instance per user identified by its session token, which live as long as user use the application.

I'm happy with such architecture, but not 100% how good it is to put `ExecutorService` instance in session as attribute.

Another approach would be to create and expose `ExecutorService` instance to be available to all user's sessions. Probably implemented as a thread safe singleton class. **BUT** if I use this approach I don't have a clue where to shut down `ExecutorService` instance and should I have to?

Here is the main question; is it OK to stay with the current implementation: `ExecutorService` instance per user stored in the current session as attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having one thread pool for each user looks nonsense, why?

You need to use `ServletContextListener` which the server invokes it once the servlet context is created and destroyed (probably application scope)

for example

```
@WebListener("daemon_dude")
public class daemon_dude implements ServletContextListener{
...
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;//or whatever type of pool
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
  scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();//and use it
}
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){
  scheduler.shutdownNow();//or any more peaceful approach
}
...
}
```